# Getting locale with NSNumberFormatter in iOS and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to make an application that receive the input from two UITextFields, multiplies them and gives back the product in a third UITextField.

```
import UIKit

class ParallelogramSurfaceArea: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sideA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var height: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var surfaceArea: UITextField!

    @IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

            let aText =  (sideA.text! as NSString).doubleValue
            let hText = (height.text! as NSString).doubleValue

            let a = round(10000 * aText)/10000
            let h = round(10000 * hText)/10000
            let sa = round(10000*(a * h))/10000

            sideA.text = "Side A = \(a) m"
            height.text = "Height = \(h) m"
            surfaceArea.text = "Surface Area = \(sa) m²"
    }
```

The problem is that on the decimal pad the ',' appears instead of the '.' because of the locale settings resulting in an error in the calculation. How can I fix this with NSNumberFormatter? Any suggestions for improving the `class ParallelogramSurfaceArea`?

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to use `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert from string to double and take in consideration the current local, `NSNumberFormatter` set the `local` value to the current locale by default

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // default value
// or custom local 
numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr_FR")

let stringValue  = sideA.text as? String ?? ""
let doubleValue  = numberFormatter.numberFromString(stringValue)?.doubleValue ?? 0.0
```

Comment: There is no need to set the formatter's locale since it defaults to the current locale.

Comment: I have updated my answer to mention that `NSLocale.currentLocale()` is the default value